# POST request on many-to-many association

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, api-platform.com

I have two entities with a many-to-many association:

```
class User extends BaseUser
```

and

```
class Calendar
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="text")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="view", type="text")
     * @Assert\Choice(choices = {"work week", "week", "month", "year"}, message = "Choose a valid view.")
     */
    private $view;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
     * @JoinTable(name="calendars_publishers",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="calendar_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="publisher_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     */
    private $publishers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->publishers = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
      * Add publishers
      *
      * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $publishers
      * @return Calendar
      */
      public function addPublisher(\AppBundle\Entity\User $publishers)
       {
          $this->publishers[] = $publishers;

           return $this;
       }

      /**
        * Remove publishers
        *
        * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $publishers
        */
       public function removePublisher(\AppBundle\Entity\User $publishers)
     {
         $this->publishers->removeElement($publishers);
      }
}
```

And when I do a POST request on my REST API (http://localhost:8000/calendars) with the body:

```
{
  "name": "My calendar",
  "view": "week",
  "publishers": [
    "/users/1",
    "/users/2"
  ]
}
```

I have the response:

```
{
  "@context": "/contexts/Calendar",
  "@id": "/calendars/3",
  "@type": "Calendar",
  "name": "My calendar",
  "view": "week",
  "publishers": []
}
```

So, as you see, my object is recorded well, but I cannot put some users in `publishers`. Do you have an idea?

I use the bundles:

- DunglasApiBundle
- NelmioApiDocBundle
- NelmioCorsBundle
- FOSHttpCacheBundle
- FOSUserBundle
- LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle

with [api-platform](https://api-platform.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `addPublisher(User $publisher)` and `removePublisher(User $publisher)` methods.

API Platform internally uses the Symfony PropertyAccess component, and this component requires such methods to be able to access to the private property.

Comment: I have already these methods, like I have edit in my post to add it.

Comment: Can you try to add a setPublishers method (without removing adders and removers)?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you should specify `fetch="EAGER"` in the relationship so that it always gets the related objects.

see http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone
(and also the next paragraph)

and some good info here: http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/some-doctrine-2-best-practices/

Comment: Specify `fetch="EAGER"` do nothing, I don't know why. So I use [Serialization groups and relations](https://api-platform.com/doc/1.0/api-bundle/serialization-groups-and-relations) and it works. I don't know if it's the cleanest way to do this.